# sql count columns group by ID

Tags: sql

counting columns group by

```
 cityID, SCity, MCity, BCity, Flag
    10,  null,  400,   null,  0
    12   350,   null,  null,  1
    13   600,   null,  null,  1
    13   700,   null,  null,  1
    15   null,  null,  250,   3
```

expected result, group by CityID,sum MCity and Display count next to City

```
cityID, SCitycount, SCity, MCitycount, MCity, Bcitycount, BCity, Flag
    10,  0,         null,   1,          400    0,         null,   0
    12   1,         350,    0,          null   0,         null,   1
    13   2,         1100,   0,          null   0,         null,   1
    15   1,         null,   0,          null   1,         250,    3
```

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT 
    cityID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 1 THEN SCity END) AS SCity,    
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 0 THEN MCity END) AS MCity,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag = 3 THEN Bity END) AS BCity, 
    COUNT(*) as count
FROM #FINALRESULTS
GROUP BY cityID
```

But this will give me one count at the end.I like to show the count column per each column

Comment: You will have to add a question(you can distinguish that by the fact that it ends with a question mark `?`) and be more verbose if you want any help from us.

Comment: Please provice some more information. Post your query. Give us information on the contextual background for understanding and about which DBMS are we talking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECt [cityID], 
COUNT([SCity]), SUM([SCity]),
COUNT([MCity]), SUM([MCity]),
COUNT([BCity]), SUM([BCity]),
[Flag]
FROM Table1 GROUP BY [cityID], [Flag]
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67331/1)**